# C# sendinput doesnt work in some applications

Tags: c#, keyboard, simulation, virtual-keyboard, sendinput

I am trying to write a little application for "auto-running" in dayz (if someone play it, know the problem of long boring running). When i started, i thought it would be simple simulating key-press and key-hold. But for now I am trying about 6hours to find the way how to code it and i am not done.

At first i tried using keybd_event of win32.dll, but nothing happens. The game looks like nothing was pressed. After that i tried SendInput, but it doesnt work as well. At last i tried search the process, its own window and use SendMessage and PostMessage in there, but nothing happens as well.

I think it is not necessary to post the code in here, because the code was simply ok :] (i tried it and everything worked with notepad and other "bordered" apps like firefox, ie, word, notepad, etc..), but nothing happens in the border-less window (in-game: Dayz).
I would like to ask:

I thought, every game communicate with operation system. And operation system with its own processor. And i thought every "process" is send to operation system and operation system then pass it to own process (application, window, etc.). So i thought the operation system has the most priority. And now i would like to ask, if its possible that the game has higher priority then operation system and the game communicate with processor? I know it is the basic of computers, but i really do not have any idea why the game didnt catch the "event" of key-press when any other application (what i tried) did.
Virtual keyboard doesnt work as well (but it is because virtual keyboard is not accessible inside the game ^^)

I never programmed any game or any graphics or any game framework so i do not know if there are some other process or something like that, but i do not think so.

Comment: Unless you give specific details don't expect any specific answers. Perhaps the game doesn't want you to cheat. Games usually don't accept fake input.

Comment: What do you mean what specific details? Code behined? I am just confused cause i thought the sendInput or keybd_event works exactly as when i pres some key. And i am not sure if any application will "block" this commands. Cause if it can block, then it must has higher priority then operation system am i right?

Comment: No you are not right. Games often get input in other ways. Ways that do not admit ready input faking.

Comment: ok, thank you sir, so that would be definitely that problem. Dont you know if there is some way how to achieve it?